# Display images in Matrix block in grid view

Tags: matrix

I have images in matrix block 
I want to display in grid format 
Each raw will have three column.

Images 1   images 2  image2
Images 4  images4  image 4

I tried to used batch filter but did not work with matrix block.

```
 {% for block in entry.profilematrix %}
{% switch block.type %}

{% case "profilebuilder" %}

{% set debfilter = block.department %}

        {# use the variable to filter the entries #}

        {% if block.department == craft.request.lastSegment   %}






                 {% for image in block.uploadImageProfile %} 




             {% endfor %}

        {% endif %}

 {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unless you receive a twig error this question has nothing to do with Craft since your html might be broken (you open `<divs>` but you might not close them properly) so it is related to html/css. You should tell us what your problem is otherwise we have to guess what is wrong. Maybe you could explain your issue a little bit better? What works/what does not work?

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply.  can you tell me how i can use the batch filter in this line a  {% for image in block.uploadImageProfile %}  and display  images in three clumn in each row.

Comment: There is actually no need for a batch filter if you have good css. As it seems this question is more about css than about Craft. You should ask about how to create a responsive grid without rows. Like that https://css-tricks.com/things-ive-learned-css-grid-layout/#article-header-id-6

Comment: Sorted. I used variable to count the matrix blocks in the loop. {% set rows = 0 %} {% if rows == 3 %}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    {% set rows = 0 %}
                                {% endif %}         only css  clound not create the grid

Answer (score 1):

```
{% for batch in block.images|batch(3) %}
  <div class="row">
  {% for image in batch %}
    <div class="column">
      <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="">
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```